# Dual Axle Tiny House Trailer Build; Question About Structural Integrity of Trailer Design

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, design, stresses, steel

I have questions about the fabrication of a tiny house trailer I am building. The questions are focused primarily whether I am adding enough cross supports.

My overarching design principle:

That of a camper toy hauler built like a split-loft Mennonite shed.

Basics:

I bought a 15' dual axle equipment trailer to modify for a build. [image: Original Trailer] It had 6000# axles. The trick is, previous owners had apparently overtaxed the trailer, weight-wise, so I ended up buying 5" C channel to more or less build a new trailer, but while trying to use as much of the older trailer as I could. The rails and cross-members of the original were a bit like spaghetti in some places; you can see one bad dip in the photo. I am now over-budget on the frame part of he build and am trying to make use of what I have, without going in for more new metal. When I realized I was in for new rails, I ended up making the trailer bed 24' long; on the original, I had not planned on extending it much.

The rails on the original were 4" I-beams, with 2 3/4" flanges. [image: I-Beam]

The cross-members of the original were 3" C Channel.[image: C Channel]

One beam is thick-walled C Channel. I am now using all of the above as cross-members. The original cross-members were on shades of 36" O.C. (no two were actually uniformly 36" apart, with some being 32" O.C.).

Current Execution:

I have 5" C Channel rails, with the tongue constructed as a single piece from the rails themselves. [image: Current Build]

The metal dealer said 5" C Channel should be sufficient.

As a bucket list item here later in life, I am in tech school five days a week, learning to weld (for a year now). Asking at school, I was cautiously told to put the original I-Beams on 4' centers and run with it. Though no engineer, I was not comfortable with that assessment--especially, given how reluctantly anyone would commit to the suggestion and when conventional builds are 2' O.C. So, I backed off and went 3' O.C., putting an I-Beam every other cross-member and then coming back with the 3" C Channel in between. It occurs to me, though, that I may have actually gone with a weaker design doing that than if I had kept the I-Beams closer together. Is that the case? I don't have all the cross-members in yet, as I wanted to situate my leaf spring hangers first, to make sure I was not cramped. That said, what you see is the designs in place, with two simply not in yet. Each rail was originally a 20' section of C Channel that I welded a 10' piece to; that is what I mean by "the joint" on the design plan. The main thing is trying to keep the weight of the trailer itself manageable. Every pound on the trailer is a pound less I have to work with on the build.

Current Design Plan: [image]

The flooring will be 2x6's on 16" O.C., with 5/8" plywood underlayment. The weight distribution of the build will be uniform, for the most part. I will have a bathroom all the way forward, with the toilet and sink on one side and a tub/shower on the other. The kitchen will be right behind it, with the sink and a 30 gallon hot water heater on one side and a gas range (smaller) and fridge (smaller) on the other. I will have a bunk loft over those. So, I'll make sure the weight of anything inside is directly over the rails. The back half of the build will be a shed/tool room/work area, with a loft for storage over that. Each section will have a loft over it. Right now, I'm looking at approximately 6000# on the build, maybe another 1200# for appliances and sundries, and, I am hoping, 1800# or less on the trailer. This trailer will not be on the road much, but won't ever have much more than that on it when moved, i.e., when it's on the road, it won't be hauling much beyond the build itself. I do want to be safe, though.

Now, when parked, I'll have it on blocks and have it loaded down over the rating. But that is only when it is is parked.

Nota bene: Though this is a toy hauler design, I will *never* have any sort of vehicle in it, not a car, not a Bobcat, tractor, or other excavating equipment, not an ATV or motorcycle, not even a riding mower. The greatest concentrated weight in the tool section will be my Snap-On tool box, which, like everything else, will be over a rail. So, there will be no danger of heavy, heavy, shifting weight on it, either loading it or when on the road.

QUESTIONS:

1. Am I okay with 3' O.C. cross-members, or do I need to beef this thing up? I am desperately hoping not to add too much more weight to it, to keep the weight of the thing down. The build is basically meant to be using the rails just like the runners that regular sheds are built on. I think the theory on the advice I got was that, because the I-Beams are so substantive, that they would suffice with less is more... I do know that most builds are 2' O.C. with lighter stock.
2. If I do need to add more support, in what way/where? Do I even need the perpendicular sections you see me planning on in two places? I thought the set at the rear door to the tool section might be wise.
3. Anything else you can think of or that I need to add clarification on?

Thanks a million for your help. I know wood, but not metal. So, I am out of my element a bit here; welding knowledge is not fabrication knowledge, after all. I just can't get straight answers from anyone on this, other than the recommended 2' O.C. rails in normal, more orthodox builds. If different or more photos are needed, I can add them; admittedly, the back cannot be seen well here.

Comment: The steel is unlikely to be your weak point if your welds are proper.  One rough way to think about it is force divided by cross section area- your wheel to frame connections likely have it going through a much smaller area of similar material so your beam spacing is not the weak point.  The issue is getting the load from your structure (floor is just osb?) to your steel beams.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, the floors will be 5/8" OSB on a standard 2x6 box frame spaced on 16" centers. It will not be straight plywood to trailer frame, if that is what you mean.

Comment: You should be a bit more concerned with lengthwise features that are needed for towing, especially on an incline as well as turning.  Think of them as helping prevent rectangles from giving way at corners (your welds). 3, 12, 18 are appropriate to keep beefy since they are close to where you concentrate load into wheels and hitch, but 6 and 9 can be skimpier.  The reason for going with more, lighter members is it allows placing material where it's needed, getting more strength for weight.

Comment: Thank you, @Abel. I had not even thought about the trailer losing square, just whether it would bend. Having planned to double up over the axles anyway, I will also look to the front thick-walled C Channel based on your thinking, to beef it up, and then trust the 4" I-Beams a little more generally, as they are on 12 and 18 already. You do not take issue with the 3' O.C. overall though, provided I keep your advice in mind about the rest? Meaning, you think the I-Beams are sturdy enough on their own, if placed properly?

Comment: Nothing wrong with 3' OC.  If I recall correctly, you can usually mount a single story 2x6 16 OC frame on piers that are ~3' apart in x and y, along just 2 layers of the perimeter (high stress areas), and ~5' apart elsewhere.